# How to unit test a function that is calling other functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs

I am testing my REST API with jest for the first time and I am having a hard time unit testing the controllers.

How should I go about testing a function that contains other function calls (npm modules as well as other controllers). Here's pseudo code. (I've tried mocking but can't seem to get it right)

```
async insertUser(uid, userObject){
// Function to check user role and permissions
const isAllowed = await someotherController.checkPermissions(uid);
//Hash password using an npm module
const pass = password.hash;
//const user = new User(userObj)
user.save();
}
```

So basically, how to test such a function that contains all these different functions.
I have written tests for simple function and they went all good but I am stuck at these functions.

Comment: Normally, you'd mock someotherController: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with https://sinonjs.org/ and mock somecontroller. Be carefull with the user.save(). It looks like you use some kind of persistence here. In case you use mongoose, you should have a look at https://github.com/Mockgoose/Mockgoose.